# MySQL Multiple Select Options

Tags: mysql, select

How can I construct a MySQL query using both the SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS and DISTINCT options?

Comment: Um, you put them into the query? I don't really understand what the question is?

Comment: How is crockets! BTW any specific queries or details of the tables

Answer (score 0):

`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` only works with the `LIMIT` clause, and allows you to use the information function `FOUND_ROWS()` to find the number of rows in the full record set without running another query to count the rows.

`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM ... WHERE ... LIMIT X;`

`SELECT FOUND_ROWS();`

Since keywords like `DISTINCT`, and `where conditions` actually affects the full record set, the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` function has no concept of what's beeing left out.  As far as I know, there are no similar information functions available for the `DISTINCT` keyword, leaving you no other option than to run the query twice.

`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ... WHERE ...;`

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... WHERE ...;`

---

NOTE: You can still use both `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and `DISTINCT` in the same query, but `FOUND_ROWS();` will only see what's left out by the `LIMIT` clause.